# Return multiple values

Tags: c++, parameters, arduino

I'm a Java developer who tries to code C++ in the limited Arduino environment. Exceptions and dynamic objects are not available or have to be avoid because of memory restrictions.

My task, create a method which parses a character buffer (hex nibble) and returns a boolean value to indicate the success as well as the actual result. My attempt so far (unrelated stuff avoided):

```
class Parser {
   unsigned char buffer[SIZE];
   unsigned char index;

   void parse();
   bool parseHexNibble(unsigned char &result);
};

void Parser::parse() {
  unsigned char result = 0;
  if (!parseHexNibble(result)) {
    return;
  }

  // do some work with result
}

bool Parser::parseHexNibble(unsigned char &result) {
  unsigned char chr = buffer[index];
  if (chr >= '0' && chr <= '9') {
    result = chr - '0';
  }
  else if (chr >= 'A' && chr <= 'F') {
    result = chr - 'A' + 10;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }

  index++;
  return true;
}
```

Will this work? I'm unsure when to use `*` and when to use `&`. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Look into `std::pair` or `boost::optional`. They're both good for this.

Comment: Please reread my first paragraph. It is a rudimentary C++ environment.

Comment: Sorry, guess I didn't read that too well O_o

Comment: This is just a hard fast rule I go by with using `*` and `&`. Use `*` when it's acceptable for the variable to be `NULL` otherwise `&`. It may not always apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways:

The way you did it is one of them, although I recommend using a pointer rather than a reference (`*` instead of `&`) because with references, the function call looks like you are passing a value (`p.parseHexNibble(c)`) while the pointer version is more clear that you may want something stored in it (`p.parseHexNibble(&c)`).

Another option, (this one is my personal favorite) is the same thing that `getc` does: Return an `int` that either contains a `char` value (`0 <= i < 256`) or is `-1` to signal an error. In the case of no error, the `int` can safely be typecast and/or stored to a `char`. (This assumes that it is a `char` in fact that you want to return.)

The third way is to return a structure containing a boolean and a character (either by making your own or by using `std::pair` or the like).

On an unrelated note, you should be using `char` rather than `unsigned char` to store actual character values. `unsigned char` should only be used for arbitrary raw data.

Comment: Thanks for clearly explaining the difference between `&` and `*`. I agree with you that `parseHexNibble(&c)` looks more clear. I already had the idea of using an `int` instead of `bool` and `unsigned char` but in that case, the further processing would keep this stupid extra byte for each variable, making each ordinary operation longer...

Comment: @MikeL. Which extra byte are you referring to?

Comment: `unsigned char`= 1 byte, `int`= 2 bytes, right? I mean the higher byte of the `int`.

Comment: @MikeL. The size of `int` actually depends on your system. Unless you have a 16-bit processor, I doubt your int is 2 bytes. It is usually 4 bytes on 32-bit machines and can be either 4 or 8 bytes on 64-bit machines. To find out, try compiling a program that prints `sizeof(int)`. Anyway, you dont need to store the value as an int any longer after you check for errors.

Comment: @Matt. An Arduino board consists of an 8-bit Atmel AVR microcontroller, according to Wikipedia.

Comment: @PeterJansson Oh sorry, I guess I kind of ignored that part of the question because "Arduino" did not ring any bells.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this should work, but note that this doesn't account for lower-case characters, but note that you forgot to return `true` for success.

Also, you methods and members are marked as `private` by default.

You should also initialize `result` in case of failure, otherwise you're risking using an un-initialized variable if you forget to check the return type.

Comment: Thanks. I used this tiny method just for explaining what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, always use & unless you need the special powers of a *. In this case, you don't need to pResult++ to point to another character, so you don't need *. A reference is "like a pointer with the indirection already turned on" (with a long list of subtle exceptions), so if you'd only say *pResult, just say result.

Next, I don't want to think about what happens when a reference seats on an unassigned variable. Just use unsigned char result = 0; to keep everyone happy. A healthy C++ coding style will always have a little extra verbosity.

Next, like the other responder implied, *also* initialize result *inside* parseHexNibble(), (such as to 0), so it has a healthy non-value if the method finds no parsable characters.

Next, the result of chr - '0' is an integer, which you then silently downcast to an unsigned char. In some situations result should be an integer, even if you indeed never use its higher bits.

And I suspect your last line should be return true.

Now my generic advice A> learn unit tests *now*, not later, and B> also learn a soft language, such as Ruby, so you know *why* C++ is so persnickety, but for good reasons.

(BTW even if your platform enabled exceptions, *never* use them to mean "this method returned a false or an out-of-band result". That way lies madness...)

Comment: Thanks. Did you ever unit-test Arduino programs? Would Ruby help me in coding such a small 8-bit uC?

Comment: I disagree about using & instead of *. (See my answer for an explanation.)

Comment: a pointer is a dangerous beast; you need some other convention to indicate the method changes that result. Using a pointer just so you can say &result is a "compilable comment".

Comment: If the method is private, its naming conventions matter less, because its calls won't reside in far-flung modules.

Comment: and instead of std::pair, assemble a 'Fallible<>' template from Barton & Nackman's /Scientific & Engineering C++/ book. A reference is a dangerous beast, too, so if a method has two outputs it should indeed return both of them.

Comment: & no I've never unit-tested Arduino, but I suspect there are Ruby-arduino packages. Those two advices were simply my standard advice to any learner, anywhere.